# React + Redux: Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I got an error message, but i'm not sure how to resolve it:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function
```

Here are the various parts of my react/redux workflow:

**root reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import PostsReducer from './reducer_posts';
import StreakReducer from './reducer_streak';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  entries: PostsReducer,
  form: formReducer,
  streak: StreakReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**action creator**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

export const FETCH_ENTRIES = 'FETCH_ENTRIES';
export const FETCH_LONGEST = 'FETCH_LONGEST';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/entries';

export function fetchEntries() {
  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}`);
  return {
    type: FETCH_ENTRIES,
    payload: request
  };
}


// action creator for returning the longest streak of rejections
export function longestStreak() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return fetchEntries().then(
      entries => dispatch(findLongestStreak(entries))
    );
  };
}


function findLongestStreak(entries) {
  var longestStreakLength = 10;
  return {
    type: FETCH_LONGEST,
    payload: longestStreakLength
  };
}
```

**streak reducer**

```
import { FETCH_LONGEST } from '../actions/index';

const INITIAL_STATE = { streak: 0 };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_LONGEST:
      return { ...state, streakInfo: action.payload.data};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Posts Reducer**

```
import { FETCH_ENTRIES, CREATE_ENTRY } from '../actions/index';

const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [], entry: null };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CREATE_ENTRY:
      return {...state, entry: action.payload.data };
    case FETCH_ENTRIES:
      return { ...state, all: action.payload.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { longestStreak } from '../actions/index';


class EntriesMetadata extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.longestStreak();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
      </div>
    );
    }
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { streak: state.streak.streakInfo };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { longestStreak })(EntriesMetadata);
```

I'm lost on how to resolve this issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction? This is my very first redux project! Please let me know if any additional snippets are needed.

**EDIT**

Here is my github repo: https://github.com/pchung39/courage

Comment: Can you show code from both reducers?

Comment: Please post code of the other reducers as well. You may get a quicker answer if you can share github link.

Comment: @HazardouS I posted my github link for this project on my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Please try as follows:
Add name to your reducer function:

```
export default function PostsReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CREATE_ENTRY
```

:
do the same with StreakReducer.
I checked my own project and this is sole difference between my and Your solution.

Comment: The javascript console still reads "Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function". I've posted my github repo for this project as an edit to my post, incase you wanted to see the whole source code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the code inside `actions/index.js`. It currently re-imports reducers and then tries to create store, which should not be there. As both reducers import this file, they end up triggering circular dependency.

You will need to fix other code errors once you have cleaned up actions code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to get why are you creating store in you actions, you already did that in your index.js right?

If you comment out store code from actions file it should work fine. Looks like a circular depedency.

Created a PR on your repository with the changes. Check it out once.

Do let me know if any you face any issues.Here is the PR [link](https://github.com/pchung39/courage/pull/1/commits)

Comment: I tried the change you suggested, and the console is stating that `return fetchEntries().then` in `src\actions\index.js` is not being recognized as a valid function? Do I need to manually import redux-promise into my app too?

Comment: is you server running on port 3000?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about mapDispatchToProps. You should pass your action with mapDispatchToProps and after what it will be accessible from props (this.props.actions.longestStreak())

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>({
    actions: bindActionCreators(longestStreak, dispatch)
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(EntriesMetadata);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan, i'll give this try and let you know!